# Is there a ASP.NET method for escaping characters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, escaping, html-escape-characters

I have created a textarea in my ASP.NET web form and it when HTML tags are entered it creates the following error:

```
 Server Error in '/GreetingCardMaker' Application.
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (setGreeting="<br />").
```

Is there a method in the .net class library that I can call on the string to remove the HTML? Or alternatively is there a method that I could write to call on the string?

Comment: Please describe your problem in more detail.

Comment: What server error? Where are you putting this? There's multiple forms of escape depending on what you want to use it with...

Comment: "these characters" is a bit too vague.

Comment: Which characters brings error?

Comment: [`HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h.aspx), however, it will not prevent you from _server_ errors but from invalid HTML.

Answer (score 3):

`HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode()` - Comes from System.Web.dll.

Perorms URL encoding on any data you get in (since pulling from request unescapes the original values)

Alternatively there is `Uri.EscapeUriString()` which does something very similar.

Answer (score 0):

This often happens when ASP.net's ["Request Validation"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339.aspx) is overzealous about blocking certain kinds of content injection (particularly HTML/XSS).

The most straightforward "fix" is to disable the checks for that stuff, but until now you were somewhat sheltered from malicious input. If you disable request validation, you have to be ready to handle potentially dangerous input yourself. I am not including the steps to disable this functionality here, because you should really know what you are doing before disabling it.

The link above is a good start, but it should not be the only thing you read on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="page.aspx.cs" validateRequest="false" Inherits="Project.UI.page" %>
```

Add validateRequest = "false" in your aspx page. This will disable input validation for the selected page.